# Facebook and Google Sign-in is not working in .aab release build. But it's working fine creating release build in .apk format

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-login, google-signin, android-app-bundle

I am getting the issue in .aab file only that google login and fb login is not working. but in .apk it is working properly, I have been stuck at this issue for the past week.

I checked SHA-1 keys properly. not issue in SHA-1 I guess.

In alerts it's showing developer_error with code 10.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you upload `aab` to Play Store? They automatically changes app's fingerprint.

Comment: yes i uploaded ab to playstore but nothing is working for me